# How do I install Urdu fonts in Libreoffice Writer like Jameel Noori Nastaleeq?

Tags: fonts

I am new user of ubuntu, i dont know how to download any urdu font in libreoffice writer??
fonts like jameel noori nastaleeq

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you install the `fonts-noto-core` package:

```
sudo apt install fonts-noto-core
```

That will provide the *Noto Nastaliq Urdu* font.